# What am I missing with my JMeter/ADFS setup?

Tags: jmeter, adfs

I am unable to get JMeter to obtain an authorization token from Azure AD in an Active Directory Federated Services setup

My organization has an ADFS setup with Azure AD.  I am able to go through the login process and obtain the MSISAuth and MSISAuthenticated cookies.  In my understanding, the next step is to obtain a "token" to submit with my next response to the Service Provider Application.  When I record using JMeter, this appears to be done using 4 variables via a redirect (code, id_token, state, session_state).  I believe the the code is the FlowToken, session_state is the sessionId and the state is a variable from a prior request that I can pass in (called state).  However, I believe that the "code" should be the contents of a cookie called "ESTSWCTXFLOWTOKEN".  When I run the flow through Fiddler, I am able to see this cookie.  However, JMeter does not seem to register this cookie in the debug sampler.  I have tried playing with the Cookie Policy in JMeter (settings tried are standard and netscape), but in either case, I am able to see other cookies but not the one I am looking for.

Looking through the contents of the ESTSWCTXFLOWTOKEN cookie via Fiddler and Base64 Decoding them, I am convinced that the authorization contents are in this cookie, but JMeter does not seem to receive this cookie.

Additional things I have tried are setting up a Reg Ex extractor on the request where the cookie is returned in Fiddler on the "Response Headers".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Edit 1:  Here are the cookies as recorded in Fiddler:

```
Cookie: ESTSSSOTILES=1;
 AADSSOTILES=1;
 wlidperf=FR=L&ST=1539195933861;
 stsservicecookie=ests;
 AADSSO=NA|NoExtension;
 ESTSSC=00;
 esctx=AQABAAAAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTTDkq2CH5PgAP0je6-RuVjdH_iStgCskVhi_rErqrj1tZ2uUin7y1uBwf2Gu2bPMwYuaaL03c-kfoiTfjyfNwfIFATiyvUgtU_4x-R0ugEbKddKU5pFMuoMyw4oiYDqTmMsSLd_PWbJrYhOq3FGv8srtpG3SC2cipDpBhn1a52rEgAA;
 CkTst=G1546370175959;
CCState=Q2xzS1MyRnVhM1Z5TG1Sb1lYZGhiaTFqYjI1MGNtRmpkRzl5UUdSemN5NWpZUzVuYjNaOFlYQndPak5sWVdWbVlqYzRMVFkwWm1VdE5HUXlZeTFpTkdJMkxUQTRaRE15TjJVeFpqTm1OQklCQUJvSkNVRnhaRzVpY3RaSUVoSUtFRTZtYWhsbzhmQkJteGZvM2YxRVFnMGFDUWxCenpRaFkzTFdTQT09;
 x-ms-gateway-slice=prod;
 SignInStateCookie=CAQABAAIAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTVF9AufyV08LEZ2xQxBiACiowK6kS3t9ij-1TgW1ZxKKWb-RQa60RKNOJxlPY1kuDB1daVGkjSy0FOWTXt5l74CAA;
 ESTSAUTHLIGHT=+;
 ESTSLOGOUTREDIRECT=MDtOQTtUcnVl;
 ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT=AQABAAQAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTzpprE-kUh2_NGHt3R3PUdiQLdju2ib1Zrp5m9o2lCrcNH8rIXzaaRQLsbrohpBFtGMsr8S02Szhu254f7dg1StCZWPKW-AoDMvoQ-uNCLzjuiEh_jRA7FekpQnpVfgwudXIzybINM19iHSxRBgOUpfwUMCr8OPOqXC2he_Q1q_bmd0OGoRbh9-L3QYw-aISL52cOhJAEDXKru_BprqoDUhXArAQ-UG4Vrkqzlzylz0F__8Pz__CYio4GmyFjDeMv4ak1l6znB_5YELZXsvYwGM-v27ynQ04FMjmGsK8G2sVC4A43aUiomsKtaTYVz5Xk1GgZeLnsKDfA-nHF1nmx85FZOX-CNI6IoQf30xx7ulcrpVW3myNtkhEA-49RAlkc03eQnxWcmNyYZY7CBoXHamor0Lftf4ceoWgQsWdWcNFvmN3J-duWSJ1NMD_gggclFZhqvzfNPk93-Q08q9WuEZE2uDJEddHm-Q9KnXhu0BsiiNCLhaIh7-mpGUBTJ0022QWdz2fJihNr9N5tegbAs7mKspDw6EmGOHsincVYuXSb35l669bWI7QcKyBDF-ZKCiowPrEg9aLaxx3MkF5pW8asiUEJiATWmyiirdQIPI3QXsp3Zqg8rnVckrpK5AAibmyqDa8g-QO_VcVv9ud7ZNrvBn6THnSblhITa9JEfDwtLmrk14-lN41RUHxZBczHjPws6IQs4cKlkSdc2B7_AFLefWk6u6eh-rzFLo29mAha6KONol57C0vYifIPrPlUS05GXdYUwLehrPfTMbfcmKYKQI-7lcR8LUFA3FFywnNi7e-p2WqjVlHaaunbgs7tUm0IDaMgJDcqpyaYNjF67pq1oXBZhuu3CyA2QFdwVVsgACAAQAAQAgAA;
 ESTSAUTH=AQABAAQAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTZ-qXDh00r1SNg9EnuNoKCV9INgj2RokuKa-kB7FuKmFt38i57Ul5C6ug4S0T6DwlsYjQgyi3iXbabJpLS-le29w5JMMzjNS9hc_TgJlyHCHuu0xkVKKyN7BZTTN-zgkBfJfW-8nDwfDM3FRLUWNQ1cKjYz17Q-dfvb0UNEU-_uIpsE4ejvQGEEbLugUax_uBZXIZYGXWPqRHB5hqbM-J0yAAIABAACAAAAA;
 buid=AQABAAEAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTFwK_PjmSKn6e7dFnjsY0ExcPKgwr76peeUbi0x9Mo4qu2WmVuQEo3JnQzBRdBmU-kEMxLQABLZnpXbx9w4zWzINPYAsyb2aNtAl_1rI_0LPlU4PNRMs9Qp75tJrpcm2NO5uBas5kUWz90czXmqrb5DaQX_insNi_QEFgFg93ZncgAA;
 fpc=ATuJtRJ2OaFJuQS3QicZ6etdyZR6AQAUbJAwY3LWCA;
 ESTSWCTXFLOWTOKEN=AQABAAEAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTl2xrzdxreg0klb7F7e5-ZnQPSWLczT4ujAuKCsyn-7-E_ArakdCZFQaMR4-RXDXbfXjOXC45fPPrR-aANusp8ytnDJSRUCSMEr80hwCbD2Yrp72LYfHZGRytvkvU5AxubKmZMooYp9sNIOnuyzfTAQ34E4ytOdbDFkJ4HYfec2_5coDrE0WMNPuveo8Au0haqqbYqM7PVqdkaafH72Og3jApeY5N_pN_sh3KauaiiJOHWnE8WrJmEQl-FF2SEux2bjQJzCwnzzNg_ZF4wc7eMtUdpfrm6JxMT1lLdAokSNXLHLEW_0VivncRwkjdZHrZB3Iu-6MCGZtNZVXwO8sD6c5I5l83bHD24j8a_AunW8qkJgb142mSCcBE0v0mBDUBIAA
```

Same request, from JMeter:
0 Cookies!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will get a comprehensive answer as [ADFS can have many faces](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/11/02/adfs-deep-dive-comparing-ws-fed-saml-and-oauth/), to wit:

- [WS-FEDERATION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Federation)
- [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)
- [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

and none of them can be actually recorded and replayed without at least performing correlation. You need to determine the underlying authentication implementation for your application and basing on this information configure JMeter for authorizing and instructions will be different.

---

With regards to your question itself (JMeter doesn't store certain cookie in the Cookie Manager) I can think of 2 possible options:

1. The cookie is malformed and JMeter simply rejects it due to some inconsistency. If this is the case you have next 2 variants:

   - raise a product issue to fix it on application side. It can be done via your project [issue tracking system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system)
   - tell JMeter to not to check the cookies and "trust" them no matter of [standard compliance](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265). It can be done by adding the next line to *user.properties* file

     ```
      CookieManager.check.cookies=false

     JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. See [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide][7] article to learn more about managing cookies in JMeter tests.
     ```
2. The cookie is being generated on **client** side (it doesn't really come from the server). If this is the case - you will have to produce the cookie from these `code`, `id_token`, `state` and `session_state` and encode it using i.e. [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) (the function is not a part of JMeter distribution, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))